# How to add a class to "li" element using role="alter" as triger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a WP website and I use a plugin called "Contact Form 7" to create a form. They provide shortcodes but I had to use the html in order to work for my client's website.

The form uses ARIA and role="alter" to display error messages when the validation fails.
I need to change the design of the boxes that failed to validate, but I cannot find a way to add the class.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="browser_gecko form_wrapper wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f46-p47-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
             <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
             <form action="/form/#wpcf7-f46-p47-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
             <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="46" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.1.1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f46-p47-o1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="229223424d" />
         </div>
         <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none validation_error"></div>
             <div class='form_body'>
               <ul class='form_fields top_label description_below'>
                 <li class='field field_contains_required' >
                   <label class='field_label'>Name<span class='field_required'>*</span></label>
                   <div class='input_container'><input type='text' name='your-name' class="large wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" tabindex='1' /></div>
                   </li>
                   <li class='field'><label class='field_label'>Company</label>
                   <div class='input_container'><input type='text' name='COMPANY' class="large wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" tabindex='2' /></div>
                   </li>
                   <li id='field_4' class='field field_contains_required' ><label class='field_label'>Email<span class='field_required'>*</span></label>
                   <div class='input_container'><input type='email' name='your-email' class="large pcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" tabindex='3' aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></div></li>
                   <li id='field_5' class='field field_contains_required'><label class='field_label'>Inquiry<span class='field_required'>*</span></label>
                   <div class='input_container'><textarea name='your-message' tabindex='4' rows='10' cols='50' class="textarea medium wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></div></li>                   
                 </ul>
              </div>
        <div class='form_footer top_label'><input type='submit' value='Submit' class="button gform_button wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></div>        
                        </form>
                        </div>
```

I want to add class "form_error" to the "li" elements when the validation fails.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you point out which element you want to target exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a CSS rule that looks for the `role` attribute, for example:

```css
[role=alter] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li role="alter">I am altered</li>
  <li>I am not altered</li>
</ul>
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: I see the logic, but my problem is that role="alter" is in a different div than the 'li' elements so it doesn't affect them.

Comment: You did not actually say specifically where the `role` attribute is assigned.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You can see its position in the HTML code I included.

Comment: I see attributes like: aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" but not "role", what am I looking for?

Comment: I am sorry. The code passes the `role=alert` to `<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>` when there are errors after the form submission.

Comment: I did some reading at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-invalid_attribute In addition to role=alert, the input field will have area-invalid=true and to check for these you will need some JavaScript or jQuery, an example is show in the Mozilla page I cited.